# CodeIgniter - foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

TL;DR
I'm trying to loop all the rows and output it with html. When I'm looping it, I get an array with the properties and values of a single row which is also the last row, when I do not loop it, I get 2 arrays (each array is a row) within an array. For some reason it doesn't loop it and display all the rows as it should, how do I fix this?

I'm trying to make a loop of sections and the articles within them, where as each article has a parent section.
In the database, there are 5 sections and 2 articles, article #1 has section #1 as it's parent and article #2 has section #2 as it's parent.

When print it as an array without looping it, I get the following array;

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 1
            [s_name] => News
            [s_slug] => news
            [s_visibility] => 1
            [s_type] => 1
            [s_status] => 1
            [s_permission] => 0
            [s_external] => 0
            [s_location] => news
            [s_color] => 1
            [s_homepage] => 1
            [a_id] => 1
            [a_section] => 1
            [a_title] => Ted Cruz’s ‘Secret’ Skill That No President Has Likely Had Since Thomas Jefferson
            [a_description] => Apparently Cruz, whose famed 2013 marathon filibuster speech over defunding Obamacare jumped across a range of topics, has an uncanny capability to remember things he hears verbatim.
            [a_content] => Apparently Cruz, whose famed 2013 marathon filibuster speech over defunding Obamacare jumped across a range of topics, has an uncanny capability to remember things he hears verbatim.
            [a_views] => 0
            [a_visibility] => 1
            [a_date] => 17.11.2015
            [a_author] => 1632422528
            [a_category] => 1
            [a_slug] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 2
            [s_name] => VOD
            [s_slug] => vod
            [s_visibility] => 1
            [s_type] => 2
            [s_status] => 1
            [s_permission] => 0
            [s_external] => 0
            [s_location] => vod
            [s_color] => 2
            [s_homepage] => 1
            [a_id] => 2
            [a_section] => 2
            [a_title] => GTA V PC Edition Released
            [a_description] => Wondering where the score is? Our GTA Online review will remain scoreless, as a score does not properly reflect its continuously changing nature. Here's how and why we decided to do it this way.
            [a_content] => Wondering where the score is? Our GTA Online review will remain scoreless, as a score does not properly reflect its continuously changing nature. Here's how and why we decided to do it this way.
            [a_views] => 0
            [a_visibility] => 1
            [a_date] => 19.11.2015
            [a_author] => 1632422528
            [a_category] => 1
            [a_slug] => 
        )

)
```

But when I run it into a foreach loop, it outputs only a single array which is the later one (1).

I'm using CodeIgniter 3, the loop is inside a library called "Global_functions",
The model is "Functions_model".

Global_functions (only the related function, not the entire class because it contains other unrelated functions):

```html
 public function get_homepage_sections()
 {

  $getHomeData = $this->CI->functions_model->get_homepage_data();



  foreach ($getHomeData as $get_sections)
  {
   switch ($get_sections['s_color'])
   {
    case 1:
     $sectionColor = "blue";
     break;

    case 2:
     $sectionColor = "purple";
     break;
     
    case 3:
     $sectionColor = "orange";
     break;

    case 4:
     $sectionColor = "green";
     break;
    
    default:
     $sectionColor = "";
     break;
   }

   $outputData = '
    <li>
     <div><h2 class="category ' . $sectionColor . '">' . $get_sections['s_name'] . '</h2></div>';
   $outputData .= '
    </li>';
  }

        return $get_sections;
 }
```

Functions_model;

```html
 public function get_homepage_data()
 {
  $selected_columns = array(
   'sections.s_id',
   'sections.s_name',
   'sections.s_slug',
   'sections.s_visibility',
   'sections.s_type',
   'sections.s_status',
   'sections.s_permission',
   'sections.s_external',
   'sections.s_location',
   'sections.s_color',
   'sections.s_homepage',
   'articles.a_id',
   'articles.a_section',
   'articles.a_title',
   'articles.a_description',
   'articles.a_content',
   'articles.a_views',
   'articles.a_visibility',
   'articles.a_date',
   'articles.a_author',
   'articles.a_category',
   'articles.a_slug'
  );

  $query = $this->db->select( $selected_columns )
   ->from( config_item('sections') . ', ' . config_item('articles') )
   //->join( config_item('articles'), 'articles.a_section = sections.s_id' )
   ->where( 'articles.a_section = sections.s_id' )
   //->or_where( 'user_email', $user_string )
   ->get();

  if ( $query->num_rows() >= 1 )
  {
   return $query->result_array();
  }
 }
```

Being called from the controller as follows (homepageSection);

```html
    public function index()
    {
    /*    if ($this->require_role('admin')) {

            echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

            echo '<p>You are logged in!</p>';

            echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
        }*/

       // return $isAutoRememberMe;
        //extra_for_auth();
        // Call a function of the model
        $data['getGlobalMessage'] = $this->global_functions->get_global_message();
        $data['userOptions'] = $this->global_functions->extra_for_auth();
        $data['homepageSection'] = $this->global_functions->get_homepage_sections();


        //print_r ($data);
        $this->parser->parse('template/header', $data);
        $this->parser->parse('sections/homepage', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

section/homepage file contains the call {homepageSection}, as you can see the parser is called and parses the file rather than loading it with view().

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: The question is in the TL;DR block.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in get_home_sections()

instead of:

```
        return $get_sections;
```

you should:

```
        return $getHomeData
```

you are returning the last item from the array, that looks like the problem you stated.

Another point i see a little bit confusing is the var you are cummulating html. 
**$outputData** is being reset in each loop, and you are not doing nothing with it. It's a good idea to initialize it at the begining of the funcion as empty string
$outputData = '';

and in the loop you should do an additive assingment with .=

Comment: Thanks you for helping out, I got it fixed already by simply moving it to the view instead of doing the loop in the library itself.